# Google spreadsheet auto count all occurances

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to make a sheet that I can use to track which heroes I need to practice in a game...

Want to manually input the following things:

- Map name (A2:A), Hero name (B2:B), Result (C2:C)

I use D2 to make a unique list of heroes I've played.

```
=UNIQUE(B2:B)
```

But then I want to add a corresponding column of wins. But I have to manually copy the function below to each row in the D2 and below... Anything to work around that?

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B;E2;C:C;"Victory")
```

Comment: You can use Apps Script to copy formulas.  The problem is finding the last row, if there are rows with formulas by no data.  But if the last row is the same as the last row with data, you can use `getLastRow()`.  You'll need to learn some JavaScript, and how to navigate and understand the Apps Script documentation.

Comment: can you share a quick sample sheet - i can almost guarantee there is an easy solution - I just need to see what we are actually working with

Comment: This question was crossposted to [webapps.se] -> http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/91280/automatically-create-an-array-of-unique-names-and-their-number-of-wins/

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14mvfbZzcAL7LJwX6MbUq_JlX_5QfDoQlfA6J5gJTg0w/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

may be, you're looking for this solution:

```
=QUERY({A3:B\B3:B};"select Col1, count(Col2) where Col1 <> '' group by Col1 pivot Col3 label Col1 'Name'")
```

[Here's Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uhSmOBXcdxWWGV1GrZvKfq6y1-K4rT-sAv5H2xELdd4/edit?usp=sharing)